# Python 3.2: how to split multiline strings into sections using groups of lines

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a file of groups of data across multiple lines.  Each section of lines of data are preceded by two lines that start with hash marks (#) and followed by a newline ('\n'), a row of dashes ('-'), then two more newlines.

In other words, the file looks something like this:

```
# Comment
# Comment
data for section 1
data for section 1
...
last line of data for section 1

--------------------------------------------------

# Comment
# Comment
data for section 2
data for section 2
...
last line of data for section 2

--------------------------------------------------

...
```

I want to break this file into each of the groups that are surrounded this way so that I can process them individually.  Since the easiest language I have on hand for file processing is Python 3.2, I've tried to build a regular expression to perform this split.  Unfortunately, I cannot get the split to work.

For example, I have successfully used the following regular expression to find the lines to ignore:

```
with open('original.out') as temp:
    original = temp.read()
print(re.findall(r'^$|^[#-].*$', original, re.MULTILINE))
```

But when I try to pass this same regular expression to `re.split()`, it simply returns the whole file.

How can I build this list of sections the way I need to, and what am I missing from my understanding of regular expressions (or how Python handles them) that would have helped me see the solution?

Answer (score 1):

**quick and dirty generator-based solution**

```
from collections import deque

# yield each section
def gen_sections(lines):
   breaker = deque(maxlen=3)
   section = []
   check = [
      lambda line: not line.strip(),       # blank
      lambda line: line.startswith('---'), # dashed line
      lambda line: not line.strip()        # blank
   ]
   for line in lines:
      line = line.strip()
      breaker.append(line)
      section.append(line)
      if len(breaker) == 3 and all(f(x) for f,x in zip(check, breaker)):
         yield '\n'.join(section[:-len(breaker)])
         section = []

# wrap file in this to remove comments
def no_comments(lines):
   for line in lines:
      line = line.strip()
      if not line.startswith('#'):
         yield line

for section in gen_sections(open('file.txt')):
  print section, '\n'
```